# NSIS doesn't backup all files

Tags: backup, nsis, move

An NSIS installer creates a fairly large folder structure. When the installer starts, it checks the registry to see if there is a current version installed...

Then it asks if you want to make a backup of the current folder.

It works most of the time, but sometimes when it is backing up older versions, instead of copying over the entire directory, it only copies the icon.

```
!insertmacro un.MoveFolder "$INSTDIR" "${BACKUP_FOLDER}" "*.*"
```

Reference: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/MoveFileFolder

```
!insertmacro MoveFolder "$INSTDIR\[path\]source-folder[\]" "$INSTDIR\[path\]destination-folder[\]" "file-mask"
```

Afterwards, it moves on to the delete section...

Could it be that it doesn't have time to do it ? it starts the next process before finishing the move ?

What else could be going on so that it does not copy the entire folder ?

During the installer, I see

```
Create folder c:\backup_folder
Moving files: c:\current_folder\*.* to c:\backup_folder\
Delete file: c:\current_folder\file1.........
```

And at the end, backup_folder has only the icon (not all the files)

Edit: The solution - please see my post here [NSIS difficulty moving folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937466/nsis-difficulty-moving-folders) - $INSTDIR is indeed a special folder so I had to move the uninstaller to a $TEMP folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you cannot use the built-in `CopyFiles` command?

To debug this I would suggest that you add a `DetailPrint` near the top of the `.MoveFolder_Locate_moveFile` function. If you see all the file names go by then the problem is the move operation in that function, if not then the problem is in the `${Locate}` macro used by this code.

Another alternative is to watch the filesystem operations with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)...

Comment: As I was looking at the output of Process Monitor (great tool !!!), I noticed that the "Result" of the "Create File" operation for every folder in the BACKUP_FOLDER is a "NAME COLLISION". That is probably the problem, but I don't understand it. The folder did not exist before, I can't see any duplicate names, the program is running with admin privileges...

Comment: I think the problem is that I am trying to move the entire INSTDIR (not a subdirectory of it) - is that possible ? I have a very hard time trying to figure out how to use absolute path names - building the BACKUP_FOLDER name from the name of INSTDIR. Is it possible to move/ rename INSTDIR to something like INSTDIR_120627 ?

Comment: $instdir is not really special, it is just a string; Messagebox mb_ok "$instdir\foo\bar" (But if you do setoutpath $instdir then windows will keep a handle open (Use setoutpath $temp before the backup operation))