# NSIS difficulty moving folders

Tags: macros, directory, nsis

I have an installer that looks for old version, and as part of the uninstall process, backs it up in a folder.

For backup, I have tried `Rename` (it sometimes fails), `CreateDirectory` then `CopyFiles` then delete them (time consuming, lots of files and directories), and have preferred to use [Move Folder](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/MoveFileFolder), where every function is replaced with its un-version (like `.MoveFolder_Locate_moveFile` -> `un.MoveFolder_Locate_moveFile`).

```
StrCpy $switch_overwrite 1
!insertmacro un.MoveFolder "$INSTDIR" "$BACKUP_FOLDER" "*.*"
```

It was working fine...

Yet I was launching the uninstaller with:

```
ExecWait '$R0'
```

As soon as I chnaged it to

```
ExecWait '$R0 _?=$INSTDIR'
```

The MoveFile gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the uninstaller without _?= causes the uninstaller to copy itself to $temp and then run a new instance from there (without waiting). You should try a hybrid of this; copy the uninstaller yourself to $temp and run it with  _?=$instdir, this should allow you to wait for the process without locking  $instdir...